# Why doesn't Python "grouping" work for regular expressions in C?

Tags: python, c, regex

Here is my Python program:

```
import re

print re.findall( "([se]{2,30})ting", "testingtested" )
```

Its output is:

```
['es']
```

Which is what I expect.  I expect to get back "es" because I searched for 2-30 characters of "e" or "s" which are followed by "ting".

Here is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(void) {

    regex_t preg;
    regmatch_t pmatch;

    char string[] = "testingtested";

    //Compile the regular expression
    if ( regcomp( &preg, "([se]{2,30})ting", REG_EXTENDED ) ) {
        printf( "ERROR!\n" );
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf( "Compiled\n" );
    }

    //Do the search
    if ( regexec( &preg, string, 1, &pmatch, REG_NOTEOL ) ) {
        printf( "No Match\n" );
    } else {

        //Allocate memory on the stack for this
        char substring[pmatch.rm_eo - pmatch.rm_so + 1];

        //Copy the substring over
        printf( "%d %d\n", pmatch.rm_so, pmatch.rm_eo );
        strncpy( substring, &string[pmatch.rm_so], pmatch.rm_eo - pmatch.rm_so );

        //Make sure there's a null byte
        substring[pmatch.rm_eo - pmatch.rm_so] = 0;

        //Print it out
        printf( "Match\n" );
        printf( "\"%s\"\n", substring );
    }

    //Release the regular expression
    regfree( &preg );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It's output is:

```
Compiled
1 7
Match
"esting"
```

Why is the C program including the "ting" in the result?  And is there a way for me to exclude the "ting" portion?

Comment: The short form of the answer is "because regex.h isn't python".

Comment: Yes, but this seems like an incredibly basic feature.  I want to match some text that appears before some other text.

Comment: OP, see my answer. This has nothing to do with C vs Python.

Comment: My question would be "why doesn't Python include it"? Seems odd to me for part of the pattern *not* to be included in the result. (But I'm not a Python guy.)

Comment: @Jefromi Python regular expressions are incredibly flexible, and I'm sure that it is possible to match the full expression and not just the subexpression.  However, what I've noticed is that Python tends to default to the operation that *most* users would want.  In my experience, when there are subexpressions specified, most users only care about the subexpressions, not the full one.  I wasn't always a Python guy, but it's growing on me.  A full specification can be found here http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: That is clear, well-written C.  And I still feel like running away screaming.

Comment: @pcd6623: I'd already looked at the docs trying to figure out why it does this - "If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups" seems like it could benefit from the addition of "and not the whole match". I guess if you wanted it, you'd have to explicitly request it as a group: `((group)restofmatch)`. I see the appeal of the whole flexible "do what most users want" approach; I guess I just don't always fit into that "most" - of course, maybe if I used it, I'd find what I expected and what I want are different :)

Comment: @pcd6623: I thought folks were using PCRE nowadays.

Comment: @tchrist I'm trying to stick with what's installed by default.  On my platform, there's regex.h but not pcre.h.

Comment: @Steven: That's not well-written C. Making a copy of a string just to print it? Dangerous use of vla's? And misusing `strncpy` as if it were `strlcpy`? Try simply `printf("%.*s\n", pmatch.rm_eo-pmatch.rm_so, string+pmatch.rm_so);` The whole `else` block reduces to a single statement with no bugs and error conditions.

Comment: @R.. I believe Steven may have been referring to my uniform spacing and bracket usage.  However, I was unaware of the existence of "strlcpy."  When I take a look at the man page for "strcpy" it only lists strcpy and strncpy, and strncpy isn't guaranteed to copy a null byte.  Thank you for the tip.

Comment: `strlcpy` is a nonstandard BSD function, but it's easy enough to write your own if it's missing. `strlcpy` does what most people wrongly expect `strncpy` to do. Unless you know what `strncpy` was originally created for and want to use it for that purpose, you should probably pretend it doesn't exist. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pmatch` is the whole match, not the first parenthesized subexpression.

Try changing `pmatch` to an array of 2 elements, then passing 2 in place of 1 to `regexec` and using the `[1]` element to get the subexpression match.

To others who have cited differences between C and Python and different types of regular expressions, that's all unrelated. This expression is very simple and that's not coming into play.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with python regex, but this would seem to be a difference - the `findall` in the example doesn't return the whole match, while regexec does (along with subexpressions). Not a difference in the regex, but a difference in the functions for using it.

Comment: Note that this is pretty much analogous to the "group" selection in python regex.  See http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regexp-Subexpressions.html#Regexp-Subexpressions for C details.

Answer (score 2):

While regular expressions are "more or less the same everywhere", the exact supported features differ from implementation to implementation.

Unfortunately, you need to consult each regex library's documentation separately when designing your regular expressions.

Comment: Good answer, I checked the docs and saw that I should have 2 pmatch's.  I was just about to accept your answer when R.. posted the exact solution.  Sorry.